# Can I create more than one FormGroup in a component

Tags: forms, angular, multiple-forms

I've created a component with 2 FormGroups

In component class:

```
//Forms for Create and Edit nodes
public formCreateCategoryInLevel : FormGroup;
public formCreateCategoryInSubLevel : FormGroup;

this.formCreateCategoryInLevel = this.formBuilder.group({
  "categoryNameInLevel":[null,[Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(80)]],
  "categoryDescriptionInLevel":[null,[Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(300)]],
});

this.formCreateCategoryInSubLevel = this.formBuilder.group({
  "categoryNameInSubLevel":[null,[Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(80)]],
  "categoryDescriptionInSubLevel":[null,[Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(300)]],
});

//My submit forms methods:
onSubmitCreateCategoryInLevel(){
   //...some code
}
onSubmitCreateCategoryInSubLevel(indexSelected_ofSubParent: number){
   //...some code
}
```

In template:

```
     <form [formGroup]="formCreateCategoryInLevel" 
           (ngSubmit)="onSubmitCreateCategoryInLevel()">
           ...
     </form>


     <form [formGroup]="formCreateCategoryInSubLevel"                
           (ngSubmit)="formCreateCategoryInSubLevel(1)">
           ...
     </form>
```

The when I call the first form submit method onSubmitCreateCategoryInLevel(), everything works perfectly, but when I call the second method formCreateCategoryInSubLevel(1) i get an Exception
[image]

As if one only one form can be created in a component, is this the case? or what?

Comment: i guess you've got a typo in your second `<form>` element, check your function name: `(ngSubmit)="formCreateCategoryInSubLevel(1)"`. You try to call the form it self...

Comment: @benny_boe  OHHH MY GOD! So much time wasted, I really need a break. Thanks though.